# cvs filenames having comma v appended

Tags: jenkins, gradle, project, cvs

There is a CVSROOT with my project on remote server. I want to set up job in Jenkins for building project into archive. Also I use cvs in that project so files over there are named like `filename,v` and gradle throws and error during building because `build.gradle` also called `build.gradle,v`. How I can do this regular build?

Comment: Is this related to cpanel somehow? I read it is creating such temporary files https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/v-files-and-their-use.46299/

Answer (score 1):

The repository on the server is intended solely as the server back-end. It is not for general use (*) and is definitely not for use as a checked-out workspace. The simplest way to think of it as an un-understandable database back-end that you'd really better not mess with, rather than noting that there is a one-to-one correspondence between files in the repo and comma-v files in the database, except for some things in Attic directories, and sometimes lockfiles. It just so happens that it's a very simple back-end format, is all.

Jenkins will need to have its own workspace checked out.

(*) Some tools like ViewVC may be given access to the repository for the purpose of indexing it into a database structure, but the general rule still remains that in general, nobody should be using the raw files on your server.